# Mac OS terminal : Select other device

Tags: mac, terminal.app

I just can't figure out how to do this.
I'm quite beginner with the terminal, I have no problem to browse between files with "cd", but don't know how to browse a different device than my hard drive (the BOOTCAMP partition for example).

Thanks for your help.

Edit : i need to do this in command line, since I have to do it from the rEFIt shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
cd /Volumes
```

You should see your other devices listed there.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't sure how to type the path to a file/folder in Terminal, you can drag-and-drop it from the Finder.  For example, type "cd " (be sure to type the space after cd), then drag in the volume/folder/whatever.  This works great for things you don't know the path to, as well as things with weird characters in the filename (spaces, Kanji, whatever).

Comment: ...but: be sure to NOT drag from the sidebar, as that will make your shortcuts disappear -- though with a nice "poof" ;-)

Comment: Good point -- Finder sidebar items are *not* draggable.

Comment: Well, they are draggable, but dragging has a different meaning to/from the sidebar. ;-)